# Infinite loop using a for loop python

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

So I'm trying to make a infinite loop that uses a for loop instead of a while loop. This is my current code. If this code works it should produce x infinitely.
Current code:

```
z=1
for x in range(0,z):
    print(x)
    z=z+1
```

Comment: And *does* it "produce x infinitely"? You *did* try it?

Comment: Is there any question ?

Comment: Thanks for telling us that you are trying to make an infinite loop.

Comment: You can use any of the infinite Iterators in 'itertools'. More here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Comment: Yes I have tested it.

Answer (score 5):

That doesn't work because the first time you enter the for loop the `range` function generates a range from zero to the value of `z` at that point, and later changes to `z` does not affect it. You can do something like what you want using, for example, [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import count

for x in count():
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

`range` returns an iterator. The iterator is already generated and evaluated before the loop iteration. (It's the returned iterator on which the loop is iterating).

The value of `z` is not used after the iterator is returned hence incrementing or changing its value is no-op.

If you really want an infinite loop using `for` you will have to write your custom generator.

For eg:

```
def InfiniteLoop():
   yield  1
```

To be used as :

`for i in InfiniteLoop()`

Answer (score 1):

Update list after each iteration make infinite loop

```
list=[0] 
for x in list:
    list.append(x+1)
    print (x)
```

Comment: I upvoted, but I also invite you to elaborate a little more. I think that some explaination may help the OP to understand the concept behind your solution, and why its use of range is not working.

Comment: Even though this works as intended, it is generally considered bad practice to add/remove elements to/from an array you are iterating over.